# How to develop a shopify application that make change in product page?

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-template

I'm trying to develop a Shopify recommendation app that will embed recommended bundle products to the shop's product page as similar as Shopify official product review app that embeds a review section (Customer Review) to the product page by adding the following section to the template:

```
<div id="shopify-product-reviews" data-id="{{product.id}}">
    {{ product.metafields.spr.reviews }}
</div>
```

:

[image: Customer Reviews]

My question is about the way of implementing a Shopify application that works as a widget in the product page. As far as I understand [Shopify App Proxy](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/embedded-apps/app-extensions/online-store/application-proxies) is doing a similar thing but it renders the template on a new page, I can't find any approach to embed my liquid template to the existing theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a beautiful and most useful aspect of App Proxy. With it you can do the following pattern, answering your needs perfectly.

- send the App Proxy the product being viewed using a Javascript GET
- The App Proxy will securely get any information you deem important for you based on the incoming product information
- You can return pure JSON data as the answer from the Proxy, back to the request
- Using any old template pattern you want, you can take the JSON returned from the Proxy and render useful HTML for the customer

While it is true the App Proxy can be used to return Liquid, this will indeed mean a re-rendering of the screen chrome and layout, so you might prefer the JS and template method. However, I have used both, and both are super for their own purposes. Returning Liquid is cool as it lets you write Liquid in the Shopify Theme that you can populate in your App, and Shopify will then populate the Product info allowing for you to have Theme Designers and the merchant change the HTML the customer sees, without the HTML template limits the JSON approach has.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any documentation or sample code that describe how can we use these approaches especially JSON based? I have tested the Liquid approach before and it re-rendered the whole of screen completely

Comment: Shopify has plenty of documentation. Thing is, if you already tested the Liquid approach, you've done most of the pattern for JSON. Change your return type to JSON, return JSON data, and then the rest is front-end work.

Comment: I can't find the correct way? What type of JSON format should I return? and how it causes the change in the product page? can you upload a basic sample code that should I return?

Comment: JSON is JSON... there is likely no incorrect way to send it out. As for samples, no. That is your simple job. There are thousands of code examples all over the Internet of how to send JSON data as a response to an Ajax request and then render that data in HTML. Try HandlebarsJS as an example if you have never tried templating before. Works most excellent.

Comment: I know what really JSON  is and I can send it as a response. I'm confused about relation of this JSON response and Shopify template. How can I provide tag for shops that shopers can use it on their template similar to Customer Review app?

Comment: JSON is data. Data is power. Send power to your template. Fill in the template blanks with Power. Feel the Power! You can do anything with this pattern dude. It is identical to the Shopify reviews one... again, if you're weak at templating, simply review the HandlebarsJS site I already pointed you to.

Answer (score 1):

I am also developing a custom product page. I guess the process should be like this:

1. When a merchant installs your app, use ScriptTag API to add your js to the product page
2. When a product page is loaded, use js to send GET request to App proxy
3. App proxy redirects to your app. Your app will return the JSON response
4. your js get and parse the response, dynamically add the widget on the product page